# Weapon guide for The Last Story

Tags: the-last-story

I'm having some trouble with planning out what weapons to upgrade in The Last Story for Wii. What typically happens is I spend a bunch of money upgrading an item to +5, use it for one dungeon, then find a better one...but it is only better if I spend a mountain upgrading it to +5. I'm currently at about chapter 15, and worried I'm wasting lots and lots of gold. I just finished equipping everyone with Gladiators, Para Axes and +5 daggers, then found I could buy Enchanters and Knight's Swords.

Is there a guide on when to buy new weapons, and when to build up money? I'm always worried that if I don't buy new weapons now I won't get a chance to later. Should I just keep using my current gear until I find weapons I don't need to upgrade so much?